# Include Log file content in mailx body

Tags: linux, bash, shell, scripting

Below script sends mail and is working. How can I include the contents of a log file present inside `/var/backup/log` inside this?

```
echo "Below are the files copied during RUN" | mailx -v \

-r "network@testserver.com" \

-s "Backup Summary" \

-S smtp="smtp.testserver.com:25" \

me@myhome.com
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Perhaps something like this : **(EDITED to remove non-printable char)**

```
(echo "Below are the files copied during RUN" && echo -e "\n----- somelogfile -----\n" && cat /var/backup/log/somelogfile) | tr -dc '[[:print:]]' | mailx -v \
-r "network@testserver.com" \
-s "Backup Summary" \
-S smtp="smtp.testserver.com:25" \
me@myhome.com
```

That solution will append the content of your log file in the mail body (the second "echo" is only there to add a reference in the mail)

Comment: mail is receiving with an attachment ATT00001.bin and the contents are messed up

Comment: You should have non printable characters in your log file.  As alternative, you can use mail instead of mailx.  Some more info about the problem here : https://access.redhat.com/solutions/1136493